# failed to connect hadoop spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am a beginner in spark job and spark configuration

I try to submit a spark job, after a few minutes (job is accepted and running during few minutes) the job fails with a connection refused.

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 2
```

```
 Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to my.domain.com/myIp:portNumber
```

I also have this error with jobs success

```
ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks
```

On my computer, with intellij Idea my job turn, this is not a code mistake

I try several time to change configuration in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml

This is a hadoop hdfs cluster, 3 nodes, 2 cores on each node, 8GB RAM on each node, I try to submit with this command line :

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3 --class MyClass --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster myJar.jar
```

mapred-site.xml :

```
<property>
   <value>yarn</value>
   <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
</property>
<property>
   <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
     <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
     <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>2000</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
   <value>0</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>ipadress</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>4000</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>500</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2000</value>
</property>
```

spark-default.conf

```
spark.master yarn
spark.driver.memory 1g    
spark.history.fs.update.interval  30s
spark.history.ui.port  port
spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout 600s
spark.default.parallelism 2
spark.executor.memory 2g
spark.cores.max 2
spark.executor.cores 2
```

Comment: What is it failing to connect to, exactly? An external server? YARN? Namenode? Also, Spark does use mapred-site

Comment: each node send a err message, `Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: hostname/ip:39318`  
and also this error
`Failed to connect to hostname/ip:39318`
but the port change each time I run the job

I launch my command on my master hdfs server , cluster mode, 
I don't know if spark use mapre-site, how to know ?

thank you